# Anaconda zip file

Tags: anaconda, conda

Is the Anaconda installer available as a zip file? The links usually used have sizes similar to or +/- 10 MB as compared to the originals. I have a hard daily usage limit and a single download will exhaust it.

Comment: What OS are you using? Is Anaconda really necessary, or could you get away with using Miniconda?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did.